# Regression coefficient in scipy curve fitting

Tags: python, scipy

I am facing the following issue.

I have this data:

x = np.array([  1.00E-03,
1.00E-04,
1.00E-05,
1.00E-06
])

y = np.array([  0.01,
0.002469136,
0.000771605,
0.000257202
])

I want to fit a power law to this data and get the regression coefficient.

However, I am getting different results between WPS office and scipy.

The code I have is the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

xdata = x
ydata = y

# Power Law function
def f(x,a,b):
    return (a*(x**b))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(f,  xdata,  ydata)

r_squared = r2_score(ydata, f(xdata, popt[0], popt[1]))
```

In WPS office I get R² = 0.9968

[image]

In google sheets the same value
[image]

Whilst in scipy, I get R² = 0.9995.

Any explanation as to why this is happening? Even with possible different algorithm, they should converge to the a similar solution, no?

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

If I change the data to a linear fit in log-log as:

```
parameters =  np.polyfit(np.log(xdata), np.log(ydata), 1)

a = np.exp(parameters[1])
b = parameters[0]
r2_score(y, a*x**b)
```

I will get the same `a` and `b` value as in excel, but now the R² = 0.9883...

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I found the answer.

The calculation of R2 is made following:  https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/r-squared/r-squared-in-excel

So:

```
x_log = np.log(x)
y_log = np.log(y)

tmp1 = len(x)*(np.sum(x_log*y_log))-np.sum(x_log)*np.sum(y_log)
tmp2 = len(x)*np.sum(x_log**2)-np.sum(x_log)**2
tmp3 = len(x)*np.sum(y_log**2)-np.sum(y_log)**2    

r2 = (tmp1/np.sqrt(tmp2*tmp3))**2
```

Yields the correct value